# Get RGB average of "CIAreaAverage" from CMSampleBuffer in Float precision in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit, avfoundation, cifilter

I am trying to get the average RGB value for my "AVCaptureVideoDataOutput" feed. I found the following solution on StackOverflow:

```
let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
let cameraImage = CIImage(CVPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage")
filter!.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
let outputImage = filter!.valueForKey(kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage!

let ctx = CIContext(options:nil)
let cgImage = ctx.createCGImage(outputImage, fromRect:outputImage.extent)

let rawData:NSData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage))!
let pixels = UnsafePointer<UInt8>(rawData.bytes)
let bytes = UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>(start:pixels, count:rawData.length)
var BGRA_index = 0
for pixel in UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes.baseAddress, count: bytes.count) {
     switch BGRA_index {
         case 0:
              bluemean = CGFloat (pixel)
         case 1:
              greenmean = CGFloat (pixel)
         case 2:
              redmean = CGFloat (pixel)
         case 3:
              break
         default:
              break
     }
     BGRA_index++
}
```

But this produces the average as an Int but I need it in a Float format with the precision kept. The rounding is quite problematic in the problem domain I'm working with. Is there a way to a Float average efficiently?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since the pixels are 8 bits the max value is 255. Assuming the floating point values are from 0.0 to 1.0 the computation should be CGFloat(pixel) / 255.0

Comment: Yeah, the problem is it outputs the average as an 8-bit int, so it rounds the float to an int... I want the floating average in the 0-255 range, without the conversion to an 8 bit pixel value

Comment: What pixel value conversion are you referring to? The pixels are represented by 8-bit values. Pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to get the average pixel value before it gets converted to an 8-bit integer - so it doesn't round as I need those minor changes at the float precision levels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I recommend using our library [`CoreImageExtensions`](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/CoreImageExtensions) for reading the value? We added methods for reading pixel values from `CIImage`s in different formats. For your case it would look like this:

```
 import CoreImageExtensions

 let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
 let cameraImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer!)
 let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIAreaAverage")!
 filter.setValue(cameraImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
 filter.setValue(CIVector(cgRect: cameraImage.extent), forKey: kCIInputExtentKey)
 let outputImage = filter.outputImage!

 let context = CIContext()
 // get the value of a specific pixel as a `SIMD4<Float32>`
 let average = context.readFloat32PixelValue(from: outputImage, at: CGPoint.zero)
```

Also keep in mind, if you want to compute the average regularly (not just once), to only create a single instance of `CIContext` and reuse it for every camera frame. Creating it is expensive and it actually increases performance to use the same instance since it caches internal resources.

Comment: This is amazing! Thanks for sharing this. Just a quick question, the floating values at in the 0-1 range. Are these calculated from the actual pixel mean values in float or is it just taking the 8-bit outputs for each colour channel and dividing by 255? I ran some experiments and it seems to be the former but wanted to double check!

Comment: Core Image actually operates with a working format that defaults to 16-bit float (you can set it as an option when creating the context, though). So when the image is loaded, it's converted to the working format before applying any filters. The 8-bit uchar values [0...255] will be translated to [0.0...1.0] then. The average is then calculated based on the float values (so it's also more precise).

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!